# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS using IIS is not working

Tags: web-application, iis, alternate-access-mapping, redirect, https

I have a Web Application. Its AAM is as follows-

```
Zone         Public URL for Zone

Default      http://sharepoint:46543
Internet     http://abc.something.com
Custom       https://abc.something.com
```

Before using IIS Rewrite module, if I access the site from any Zone it works fine.

But once I configure Rewrite module as following-

***Match URL Section***

```
Requested URL               = Matches the Pattren
Using                       = Regular Expression
Pattren = (.*)
```

***Conditioins***

```
Logical Grouping            = Match All
Condition Input             = {HTTPS}
Check if input string       = Matches the pattren
Pattren                     = ^OFF$
```

***Actions***

```
Action Type                  = Redirect
Redirect URL                 = https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}
Append Query String          = True
Redirect Type                = See Other (303)
```

If I try to access the site on the `Web Front Server` i.e. using Default Zone `http://sharepoint:46543` the website does not open. Even Central Administration stop opening at this time.

If I try to access Internet Zone `http://abc.something.com` then it gets redirected to Custom Zone `https://abc.something.com` but it does not open the site. Even if I try to access Custom Zone site by directly entering the URL, it does not open.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this-

1. Removed the `IIS Rewrite` rules completely.
2. In AAM, Default Zone `http://sharepoint:46543` remain same
3. Click on `Edit Public URLs`, enter `https://abc.something.com` (HTTPS) in Internet and Click Save.
4. Click on `Add Internal URLs` and enter `http://abc.something.com` (only HTTP) and `Save`.

> Source - http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/20/a-guide-to-https-and-secure-sockets-layer-in-sharepoint-2013/